# python logging-Error in the number of log records

Tags: python

i define a log class,the purpose is to record the log and print to the screen at the same time, here is my log class file(utils/mylog.py):

```
import logging
import os
import time

class MyLog(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logfile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"..")) + '\logs\\' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d',time.localtime()) + '.log'
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-12s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(name)-10s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

        self.loghand = logging.FileHandler(self.logfile)
        self.loghand.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.loghand.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.loghandst = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.loghandst.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.loghand)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.loghandst)

    def debug(self,msg):
        self.logger.debug(msg)

    def info(self,msg):
        self.logger.info(msg)

    def warning(self,msg):
        self.logger.info(msg)

    def error(self,msg):
        self.logger.error(msg)

    def critical(self,msg):
        self.logger.critical(msg)
```

and this is a test file in the same directory(utils/testlog.py):

```
from utils.mylog import MyLog

class TestA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = MyLog()

    def run(self,a,b):
        self.log.debug('calc a + b:%d + %d' %(a,b))
        return a + b

class TestB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = MyLog()

    def run(self,a,b):
        self.log.warning('second calc a + b:%d + %d' %(a,b))
        return a + b + 6

class TestC():
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = MyLog()

    def run(self,a,b):
        self.log.critical('third calc a + b:%d + %d' %(a,b))
        return a + b + 6


if __name__ == '__main__':

    task1 = TestA()
    task1.run(12,56)
    task2 = TestB()
    task2.run(10, 56)
    task3 = TestC()
    task3.run(77,88)
```

and the result :

```
2018-05-28 16:49:08,992 mylog.py[line:27] root       DEBUG calc a + b:12 + 56
2018-05-28 16:49:08,997 mylog.py[line:33] root       INFO second calc a + b:10 + 56
2018-05-28 16:49:08,997 mylog.py[line:33] root       INFO second calc a + b:10 + 56
2018-05-28 16:49:08,997 mylog.py[line:39] root       CRITICAL third calc a + b:77 + 88
2018-05-28 16:49:08,997 mylog.py[line:39] root       CRITICAL third calc a + b:77 + 88
2018-05-28 16:49:08,997 mylog.py[line:39] root       CRITICAL third calc a + b:77 + 88
```

ereything works well, create log file and print log in screen, but why task 2 and task 3 have more than one record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logging.getLogger()` always returns the same logger (in this case the root logger), so you keep on adding handlers to your root logger each time you instanciate a new `MyLog` instance.

FWIW your whole `MyLog` class is a very bad idea - actually an anti-pattern. The code *using* loggers (let's call it "library code") should not in any way configure the loggers - only ask for them (using `logging.getLogger(<name>)` and use them, and the configuration should be handled by your application's entry point.